# maven: multi module HAR dependencies

Tags: maven-2

I have a multiple module project

The first module contains my hibernate xml files and data java beans and
packages as har.
The second module defines my DAO classes. This module has a dependancy on
data java beans with in the har and is defined in pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myhar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>har</type>
    </dependency>
```

The first module compiles, packages and installs fine into my local
repository.
The problem is when the second modules compiles it has
a problem finding the packages and class defined in my har module. I get the
following output from running mvn install

`package myproject.myhar does not exist`

and build fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't use the har type (plugin)..and if i understand the thing correct you have to go a different way. You har should be simple jar file which will be used by your dao module...and the two together could be used as a single har file. But why not using simple war/ear files instead for JBoss?